# Reading a Stop Signal within a loop

Tags: c, unix

I am using a while loop which doesnt terminate,  for reproducing Tail command of unix using C code. I need a way to stop the loop apart from Ctrl + C which quits the process i believe. Is there any way to read Keyboard commands when used within the code ? The problem with using getchar() is that it stops the loop from running until a char is entered. Is there any alternative solution to this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to make your program interactive ? See http://fmg-www.cs.ucla.edu/geoff/interfaces.html#interactive

Comment: You can simply catch ctrl-c (sigint).

Comment: you should read about Unix signal handling.... get an idea from [this](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html)

Comment: You should read about how to set a terminal in raw mode and reading from /dev/tty (I assume stdin is used for other input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn off blocking and line buffering. Turn off blocking so `getc()` returns right away. It will return -1 until it has a real character. Turn off line buffering so the OS sends the char right away instead of buffering it up until it has a full line which occurs when you press return.

```
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

int main(void) {

    // Turn off blocking
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    struct termios options, oldoptions;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &options);
    // Disable line buffering
    options.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON);

    // Set the new options for the port...
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &options);

    while(1) {
        char c = getc(stdin);
        if(c != -1) break;
    }

    // Make sure you restore the options otherwise you terminal will be messed up when you exit
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldoptions);

    return 0;
}
```

I agree with the other posters that you should use `signals`, but this is the answer to what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like [this question from the comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html).

Q: How can I read a single character from the keyboard without waiting for the RETURN key? How can I stop characters from being echoed on the screen as they're typed?